# How can I avoid having two instances of a very large matrix at the same time when loading it into a solver?

Tags: matlab, matrix, space, linear-programming

I am using both Cplex and Gurobi for an LP program whose inequality constraint matrix A can become truly large -- around 5 to 10GB. When I want to use one of those solvers, I have to create a separate struct with all the problem constraints. This means that I have the matrix A in my workspace, and the matrix A in my solver struct at the same time. Even if I clear it in my Workspace as fast as possible, there is still a time when both exist and my RAM is overloaded.

I am asking if there is some clever method to deliver the matrix A into the model without both existing at the same time. The only thing I can think of right now is delivering it in small chunks...

Comment: Depends in the code, but you need to show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB using copy-on-write, or lazy copying. This means that, as long as you don't modify one of the copies, all copies of a matrix share the same data:

```
A = randn(10000);
B = A; % does not take up extra memory
myfunc(B);

function myfunc(matrix)
   C = matrix; % does not take up extra memory.
```

For reference, see for example on [Loren's blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/) and [Undocumented Matlab](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations).