# Extract contents from cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a series of Images, stored into an array A. So every entry of A contains an Image (matrix). All matrices are equally sized.

Now I want to extract the value of a specific position (pixel), but my current approach seems to be slow and I think there may be a better way to do it.

```
% Create data that resembles my problem
N = 5
for i = 1:N
A{i} = rand(5,5);
end

% my current approach
I = size(A{1},1);
J = size(A{1},2);
val = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:I
    for j = 1:J
        for k = 1:N
            B(k) = A{k}(i,j);
        end
        % do further operations on B for current i,j, don't save B
    end
end
```

I was thinking there should be some way along the lines of `A{:}(i,j)` or `vertcat(A{:}(i,j))` but both lead to

```
??? Bad cell reference operation.
```

I'm using Matlab2008b.

For further information, I use fft on B afterwards.

Here are the results of the answer by Cris

```
|     Code     | # images | Extracting Values |   FFT    |  Overall  |
|--------------|----------|-------------------|----------|-----------|
| Original     | 16       | 12.809 s          | 19.728 s | 62.884 s  |
| Original     | 128      | 105.974 s         | 23.242 s | 177.280 s |
| ------------ | -------- | ----------------- | -------  | --------- |
| Answer       | 16       | 42.122 s          | 27.382 s | 104.565 s |
| Answer       | 128      | 36.807 s          | 26.623 s | 102.601 s |
| ------------ | -------- | ----------------- | -------  | --------- |
| Answer (mod) | 16       | 14.772 s          | 27.797 s | 77.784 s  |
| Answer (mod) | 128      | 13.637 s          | 28.095 s | 83.839 s  |
```

The answer codes was modded to `double(squeeze(A(i,j,:)));` because without double the FFT took much longer.

Answer (mod) uses `double(A(i,j,:));`

So the improvement seems to really kick in for larger sets of images, however I currently plan with processing ~ 500 images per run.

**Update**

Measured with the `profile` function, the result of using/omitting squeeze

```
|              Code              | # Calls |   Time   |
|--------------------------------|---------|----------|
| B = double(squeeze(A(i,j,:))); | 1431040 | 36.325 s |
| B= double(A(i,j,:));           | 1431040 | 14.289 s |
```

Comment: I do not get that in 2017a. Which MATLAB version are using? Have you tried adding `clear` on top of this script before testing?

Comment: For speed and practicality, if your images are all the same size, consider using a 3D matrix `A(i,j,k)`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I added the version info, forgot that this may be important. I tested the script, and yes I cleared all before.

Comment: If removing the `squeeze` reduces the time to 1/3, something is wrong in how you time. Did you write the code within a `function` M-file?

Comment: That’s a surprising overhead for the `squeeze` function. It doesn’t even copy any data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A{:}(i,j)` does not work because `A{:}` is a comma-separated list of elements, equivalent to `A{1},A{2},A{3},...A{end}`. It makes no sense to index into such an array.

To speed up your operation, I recommend that you create a 3D matrix out of your data, like this:

```
A3 = cat(3,A{:});
```

Of course, this will only work if all elements of `A` have the same size (as was originally specified in the question).

Now you can quickly access the data like so:

```
for i = 1:I
    for j = 1:J
        B = squeeze(A3(i,j,:));
        % do further operations on B for current i,j, don't save B
    end
end
```

Depending on the operations you apply to each `B`, you could vectorize those operations as well.

**Edit:** Since you apply `fft` to each B, you can obtain that also without looping:

```
B_fft = fft(A3,[],3); % 3 is the dimension along which to apply the FFT
```

Comment: Only works if all `A` are the same size! However OPs code does work in recent versions of matlab. Not the `{:}`, but the loop

Comment: @Ander: OP edited out "contains matrices (all of the same size)" from the question...

Comment: @AnderBiguri after your original confusion about my question I changed equally sized matrices to images. And also the code I posted works in 2008b, just my ideas for improvement didn't. And since I probably can't get around 2 for loops to access each pixel, I at least wanted to save the loop for accessing all images. I'll accept the answer tomorrow if it runs on my version.

Comment: Images are matrices @idkfa, its the same thing. The important thing for Cris was if they are the same size.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I thought an image series would imply equally sized matrices, my `% Create data` part also generated equally sized ones. But I should know that thinking something would imply something, doesn't fly when asking questions, especially programming ones.

Comment: @idkfa considering also that in reality, different sized images do in fact exist, as you probably know. If that is the case, then ditch cell arrays, they are inefficient and impractical. Use 3D matrices.

Comment: @Ander: [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50300747/7328782) is relevant to your last comment. -- sometimes cell arrays are a better approach, but it all depends on what processing needs to be done. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Your approach seems to work well for larger data sets. I added info in my original question. Since you mentioned a dependency on the further processing, I added that this would be a fft.

Comment: @idkfa: check the update, you can compute all FFTs without loops.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Excellent! This saves a lot of time. The only downside is, that all subsequent operations (getting the single sided spectrum out of the fft) lead to massive memory problems (although I have 16GB)  if my image series contains too many images. But since my question has been answered I'll leave that for another one if I can't figure it out myself. I also added information about my timing, as per your comment.